# How to run Docker images registered on Docker.com?

Tags: docker

I have an account on hub.docker.com, and I successfully built an image, ran `docker login` to temporarily log me in to my account, and then uploaded my image with:

```
docker push myusername/myrepo:latest
```

and the upload succeeded.

Now I'm trying to run that image on a new machine that has Docker installed but doesn't yet have the image. I successfully ran `docker login` on the new machine to log myself in, but when I try to download my image with:

```
docker pull myusername/myrepo:latest
```

it fails with the error:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for myusername/myrepo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
```

As both the repository exists, and my login succeeded, I'm not sure how to proceed. What is the actual reason why the pull is failing?

I'm using Docker CE version `18.09.6, build 481bc77`.

Answer (score 0):

For worked trying

```
docker logout
```

and then

```
docker login
```

with the proper credentials.

Note : Also check following things.

1) If you login using your email address, try logging using docker hub id.
If you go to DockerHub you should see it in the upper right corner.

2) Check Docker hub whether your image is available public or private ?

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I'm logging in with the identical credentials that I use for the website, and yes, my repos private. Does it matter if it's public or private? Does a private repo mean that not even the owner can access it?

Comment: Did you login using your email or docker user name ?

Comment: Did you follow the all steps ?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/push/

Comment: I just tested the same process with Gitlab, and it works perfectly using the same commands that Docker's site says I should us. Possibly Docker's site is buggy? Not a good sign when their competitor is running a better site than the product's inventor...

Comment: yeah. true. :) i will look into docs also. if you find an answer. please update me also. thanks.